# How to best set up encryption for files uploaded to aws?

Tags: amazon-web-services, firebase

I am doing firebase backups and am trying to figure out the best way to keep the data secure and encrypted.

I was told by firebase to provide a public PGP key but AWS also has a Key Management System (KMS) to create keys.  I created a key but not sure where to get the public key version of it to give to firebase?

Not sure if I'm doing this right but let me know if you have advice on how to best secure the bucket and the data it has.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set up "basic" SSE (Server Side Encryption) with AES256 which is the default. With this, and a bucket policy that denies any uploads that don't have the SSE header, you should be fine.

This is a pretty decent level of encryption as each object is encrypted with a unique key and as an additional safeguard, it encrypts said key with a master key which is regularly rotated by AWS itself.

To set this up, basically you apply the following bucket policy:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Id": "PutObjPolicy",
  "Statement": [
  {
    "Sid": "DenyIncorrectEncryptionHeader",
    "Effect": "Deny",
    "Principal": "*",
    "Action": "s3:PutObject",
    "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::YourBucket/*",
    "Condition": {
    "StringNotEquals": {
      "s3:x-amz-server-side-encryption": "AES256"
    }
  }
},
{
  "Sid": "DenyUnEncryptedObjectUploads",
  "Effect": "Deny",
  "Principal": "*",
  "Action": "s3:PutObject",
  "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::YourBucket/*",
  "Condition": {
    "Null": {
      "s3:x-amz-server-side-encryption": "true"
    }
  }
 }
 ]
 }
```

This will only accept `putObject` requests that have the following request headers:

```
"x-amz-server-side-encryption":"AES256"
```

You can also set up your own KMS(Key Management System) but I believe it's rather pricey.

Comment: thanks @tom!  few questions - so this encrypts objects after they hit aws, correct?  wouldn't you want the objects encrypted before they are sent to aws with a public key?

Comment: This is completely up to you although if you send your data over HTTPS which uses TLS (Transport Layer Security) 1.2, it should already be encrypted. If you'd like to go for a paranoid level of security, you could even encrypt it before you send it over the wire which, if you ask me, isn't necessary.